# Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios

I am trying to run an application in iphone4 device but not able to build an app, getting following error :

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

if any one knows solution please help..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Relaunch XCode, then try creating a new project and see if the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

In project build settings try removing the build settings for "Other Interface Builder Compiler Flags" (if -Wmost is set, set it to nil).

Project --> Build settings ---> Other Interface Builder Compiler Flags --> set to none(empty).

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem in Xcode 7.2.1 and spend 3 hr to figure out the exact issue .

Most of the answer dint solve my problem so  thought to share solution here :

Applying wrong Constraint (either Autolayout or Size class) may produce this error , just go through the runtime warning by autolayout and fix it which finally solve **uer bin - ibtool issue** .