# /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255, Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I know this issue appears quite a lot but it seems like it is every time for a different reason. So when I try to build I get this error :

> Command /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
>   failed with exit code 255

And when I try to open main.storyboard, Xcode quits and I have this in the log :

> Details:  Failed to compute auto layout status IBLayoutConstraint and
>   IBUILabel.   Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder
>   Cocoa Touch Tool. If you choose to file a crash report or Radar for
>   this issue, please zip and attach the diagnostics at
>   "/var/folders/wv/vs8lxfzd7t3fl5jlckbcjlvh0000gr/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-11-17_17-20-58_309000"
>   to your crash report.   Exception name: NSGenericException Exception
>   reason: Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint
>   reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's
>   illegal. constraint: view:>

I tried several things, cleaning the project, restarting Xcode and rebooting the computer, to no avail. I looked at the flags for IB like said at this question : [Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463383/command-applications-xcode-app-contents-developer-usr-bin-ibtool-failed-with-ex), but I don't have any. I opened IB in code, try to give it a look but it's quite massive, however all the 
`setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` are set to `NO` inside. (This is also a solution I have seen mentioned in several places.
I should mention that I tried opening an other project and it worked perfectly well, so I guess it comes from this project, which is strange because it comes somebody else and it worked well on his computer, so some strange combination of project-xcode guilt.
Thanks for your help,

PS : And last, I am using Xcode-beta, version 7

**EDIT**
I also tried removing everything at this path `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes.`,(an other often seen solution for this error) though it didn't seem very related to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already this question is in stack overflow. 
Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15422271/5019395)

Comment: Ok, I missed this question, to my defence there are really a lot of title with this error but each time with different source. Anyway, thanks for the link, seems odd that Xcode has been dragging this bugs since at least Xcode 4.6